# relation between 1-chain and edges of the universal covering

Tags: graph-theory

let $G$ be a graph with a finite set of vertices $V$ and a finite set of edges $E$. Let $\Omega$ be the universal covering of $G$ with set of vertices $\tilde{V}$ and set of edges $\tilde{E}$. There is a projection map $\tilde{E}\rightarrow E$. I would like to know in which cases this can be refined to a $\pi_1(G)$-invariant morphism $\tilde{E}\rightarrow C_1(G,\mathbb{Z})$ where the action of $\pi_1(G)$ on $C_1(G,\mathbb{Z})$ is given by the composition $\pi_1(G)\rightarrow H_1(G,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow C_1(G,\mathbb{Z})$. For example if $G$ has one node and one edge $a$ I can fix a vetex $p_0\in \tilde{V}$. Given $e\in\tilde{E}$, there is a shortest path $\gamma$ from $p_0$ and the source of $e$ and I get $\gamma\cup e= e_1\cup \dots\cup e_r\cup e$, since all $e_i$ project to the unique edge $a$ I get $(r+1)a\in C_1(G,\mathbb{Z})$. Given $g\in\pi_1(G)$ then the path $\overline{e,ge}$ is obtained by adding $x$ copies of $e$ where $x$ represents $g$ in $H_1(G,\mathbb{Z})$, so that $\gamma\cup \overline{e,ge}$ gives $(r+1+x)a\in C_1(G,\mathbb{Z})$.

Any reference would be very much appreciated

Thanks